# Restriction of scalars

Tags: algebraic-groups

Could some one help me with understanding the notion of restriction of scalars? For instance in the case of algebraic group, for instance, $GL_N$, what does restriction of scalars from $K$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ mean, where $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is a finite field extension over the rational numbers?

How to embed $GL_n(K)$ inside $GL_N(\mathbb{Q})$ where $N= [K:Q] \times n$ concretely?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean Weil restriction?

Comment: These notes, which come up immediately if you google, seem to explain it very nicely: http://math.uga.edu/~pete/SC5-AlgebraicGroups.pdf

Comment: Yeah, I mean Weil restriction.  I wanted to see how the domain group sits in the target group, concretly.  In one notes I searched for, the image of the source group is characterized as the set of matrices in the target group that commutes with the scalar multiplication map $\theta : K \to End_{\mathbb{Q}}(V_0)$ where $V_0$ is the vector space corresponding to $GL_n$.

Comment: @David Loeffler, thank you very much. I will look into the notes